# Flex Tasks // Mxmlc and native extension (ANE)

Tags: flash, command-line, mxmlc, air-native-extension

I need to setup a continuous environment allowing to build air apps, and so I have to setup some ANT script to compile my flash then package it.

I came across the flex task mxmlc which is the base tool to build .swf.

I have setup a base build file using this tool, but my project uses .ANE, and I cannot get them to be included as my swf compiles. I end up with errors as many classes are unknown.

Here is my build file:

```
<property
    name="AIR_SDK_HOME" value="${basedir}/Flex 4.6.0" />    

<property
    name="FLEX_HOME" value="${basedir}/Flex 4.6.0" />   

<property
    name="FLEX_TASKS" value="${FLEX_HOME}/ant/flexTasks.tasks" />       

<property
    name="ADT" value="${SDK}/bin/adt" />        

<property
    name="MXMLC" value="${SDK}/bin/amxmlc" />   


<taskdef resource="flexTasks.tasks" classpath="flexTasks.jar"/> 


<target name="compile">
    <mxmlc file="${basedir}/src/Main.as"
        output="${basedir}/bin-debug/HR_2012_IPAD.swf"
        locale="en_US"
        static-rsls="true"
        accessible="true"
        configname="airmobile"
        debug="true"
        failonerror="true"
        fork="true"
        maxmemory="512m">
        <source-path path-element="${FLEX_HOME}/frameworks"/>
        <source-path path-element="${basedir}/src"/>
        <source-path path-element="${basedir}/gestouch"/>  
        <compiler.library-path dir="${basedir}/lib" />

        <compiler.external-library-path dir="${basedir}" append="true">
            <include name="lib/*" />
        </compiler.external-library-path>

        <library-path dir="${basedir}/lib" includes="*.swc,*.ane" append="true"/>
        <library-path dir="${SDK}/frameworks/locale/en_US" includes="*.swc" append="true"/>

    </mxmlc>
</target>
```

If anyone has already managed to successfully include .ane using mxmlc, I would love to hear a solution.

Cheers guys!

Answer (score 1):

Adding the path, as well as the .ane file name to **-external-library-path** works for me.

**EDIT:** In your target you may only have to change this to explicitly look at the .ane file:

```
<compiler.external-library-path dir="${basedir}" append="true">
   <include name="lib/yourExtension.ane" />
</compiler.external-library-path>
```

---

This is how I use it (${compiler.arguments} is optional - you can use it to pass info to the compiler, for example define labels for conditional compilation like this: CONFIG::debug_trace,true):

```
<target name="build" depends="set build type, copy extension packages, copy files for building">
        <exec executable="${MXMLC}" failonerror="true">
            <arg line="
                ${compiler.arguments}
                +configname=airmobile
                -debug=${build.debug}
                -output ${app.builddir}/${app.name}.swf
                ${app.main.file} 
                -source-path+=${app.sourcedir}
                -external-library-path+=${ext.extensiondir}/${ext.file}
                -library-path+=${app.libs}
                -incremental=true
            "/>
        </exec>
    </target>
```

This is an excerpt from the continuous environment build scripts I wrote for our book [Easy Native Extensions](http://diadraw.com/easynativeextensions/) (the goal is to do a build of the ANEs, the app that uses the ANEs and install the app on the device with a single click).

Comment: All right, I'll try this right away.
Do you think I need to use "exec" in this case specifically? Or can I stick with the <mxmlc> task ?

Comment: Your way is OK, I think, no need to change the whole target.

Comment: All right, I think I'm going to stick with yours and directly call the MXMLC.jar to compile.
I'm getting a few issue though, I should organize this the way you did.
What does ${compiler.arguments} refers to? Is that all the "--" ? Such as:
--compiler.library-path+=
--compiler.debug=true

Comment: Hi Thomas, in my target ${compiler.arguments} is there for flexibility, so you can add any other arguments that are not defined in the target. So you probably don't need that at all. I've edited my answer for clarity. Does it work for you, if you put the .ane file name explicitly in <compiler.external-library-path>, <include> in your Ant script?

Comment: I have added ane in same a same way but it is not working for me still giving me error - "An implementation for native extension 'com.example.mobile.extensions.NativeFeatures' required by the application was not found for the target platform."